# SVN commit ignoring carriage return

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am sorry if this question has already been asked in different forms, but I did a search and was not able to find exactly what I am looking for, and that is why I am posting here.

I know that I can use external diff tools (e.g. WinDiff) to perform the diff between what is in the repository vs what is on my local machine, and I can apply certain filters to those tools to ignore the carriage return at the end of the files. This works fine, and I can see that the external tool actually doesn't show the diff between the carriage returns at the end of the files, between Dos and Linux.

However, the problem that I am having is that I would like to do the same thing when I am committing (checking in) the files back to the repository !! I would really like to see if there are ways that SVN "commit" can ignore carriage returns at the end of the files, when I am checking files in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `svn:eol-style` property to the `native` value for each "text" file already in the repository.

```
svn propset svn:eol-style native MyFile.cpp
```

Once done for a file, you don't have to do it again.

For new repository, and or new files added to an existing repository, there is ways to make the property to be a default one, but that depends on your version of SVN.

EDIT: for setting properties using Tortoise SVN, see [Subversion Properties](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html).